# nexus2artifactory Maven Snapshot Version Behavior

Tags: maven, nexus, artifactory

I'm using [nexus2artifactory](https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory) tool to migrate form nexus to artifactory (as tool's name obviously says) and am facing a strange behavior and was wondering if I'm doing something wrong.

I'm trying to migrate some maven repositories created  on nexus which handle snapshots and which should be set with UNIQUE as "Maven Snapshot Version Behavior" (default when creating a maven repo in Artifactory) but after the migration all my snapshots repos are set with NON-UNIQUE which is quite annoying especially when using maven3 where the support for *uniqueVersion* tag was dropped.

Am I alone with this problem ? What can I do to migrate these repos differently ?

Thank you in advance for your kind explanation

Comment: Do you need to use `uniqueVersion`?

Comment: No, I'd like to avoid that as much as possible, however this would be the only solution to get artifacts from a repository set up the way it is now. But anyway this is not supported in maven3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the nexus2artifactory tool is using the Artifactory REST API for [creating](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateRepository) the repositories.
The default value for [snapshotVersionBehavior](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Configuration+JSON#RepositoryConfigurationJSON-application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.repositories.LocalRepositoryConfiguration+json) when working with the REST API is non-unique (for legacy reasons).

This should be [fixed](https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory/issues/5) in the nexus2artifactory tool (and possibly also [change](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-14440) the REST API defaults). In the meantime, if you need a quick fix, the following could be added to [Artifactory.py](https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory/blob/master/nex2art/core/Artifactory.py#L159):

```
jsn['snapshotVersionBehavior'] = 'unique'
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this clear explanation, it totally makes sense, I'll try the fix and will also propose a pull request for that (if needed)

Comment: As written above, here is a proposal as a PR on the relevant repo:
https://github.com/JFrogDev/nexus2artifactory/pull/6